# How to pass multiple parameters in UiChild tags in GWT?

Tags: gwt

The GWT xml looks like:

```
<my:CustomWidget>
  <my:tag para1="a" para2="b"/>
</my:CustomWidget>
```

And how can I get these 2 parameters in Java code? Similar to the codes below:

```
@UiChild(tagname = "item")
public void addItem(String para1, String para2) {
  //......
}
```

PS: the above Java code doesn't work.

Is there any other ways to get parameters by using UiChild tag in GWT?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the `@UiChild` at your `CustomWidget` level:

```
class MyCustomWidget extends Composite {
    @UiChild(tagname = "tag")
    public void addTag(Tag tag) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

and the parameters in your constructor's `Tag` class, annotated with `@UiConstructor`:

```
class Tag extends Composite {
    @UiConstructor
    public Tag(String para1, String para2) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```